# Получение коллекции обновляемых TableAtaper'ом записей (C#)

Tags: c#

Не могу решить проблему несколько дней, поиск ничего не дал..
В общем, на примере например DataGridView:
при использовании ...TableAdapter.Update()  --TA естессна заполняет DGV
он каким то образом сам понимает, к каким записям применить Update, или Insert/Delete
Следовательно следуя логике, где то указано что произошло с каждой записью..
Мне очень хотелось бы получить записи с которыми происходит то или иное событие.
например банально используя foreach и проверяя какое то свойство..
Помогите пожалуйстаа..
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: `TableAdapter` совершенно не при чем. Коллекция ваших записей содержится в `DataTable`. Каждая запись (`DataRow`) имеет свойство [RowState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.rowstate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataRow_RowState). Адаптер именно это свойство проверяет, когда выполняет какие-либо операции.

Comment: Такс, а не подскажите как обратиться к нужному DataTable?

Comment: Это тот `DataTable`, который привязан к `DataGridView`.